# What is the best symbol to use for the d'Alembertian?

Tags: symbols

Normally, most people use the symbol $\Box$ to represent the [d'Alembert (wave) operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) (including the linked to Wikipedia page).

Recently I wanted to use `\hat\Box` and `\tilde\Box`, but they do not render very well.

[image: boxes]

What is the "best" way to create such symbols?

---

Aside: The above image is rendered using my local install of pdflatex: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`. The symbols seem to render fine on some online services: e.g. "[Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)" produces

[image: more boxes]

from

```
\begin{align*}
\Box &= \sum_a \partial^a\partial_a \,, &
\hat\Box &= \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a
\end{align*}
```

Comment: +1 I would like to see a symbol that looks well when use with `\nabla` and `\Delta`. These symbols have heavier line width than `\box` which makes the latter look odd..

Comment: @romeovs: I don't use `\nabla` or `\Delta` much, but I see your point. Maybe it's worth its own question?

Comment: Related Question: [Typeset d'Alembertian operator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175828/typeset-dalembertian-operator-in-classicthesis).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The character bounding box of `\Box` is wrong, the height is too low, when `latexsym` is used as package to get the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\[ \fbox{$\Box$} \fbox{$\hat\Box$} \fbox{$\tilde\Box$} \]
\begin{align*}
\Box &= \sum_a \partial^a\partial_a \,, &
\hat\Box &= \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result latexsym]

Using `amssymb` instead fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\[ \fbox{$\Box$} \fbox{$\hat\Box$} \fbox{$\tilde\Box$} \]
\begin{align*}
\Box &= \sum_a \partial^a\partial_a \,, &
\hat\Box &= \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result amssymb]

Answer (score 11):

I try with `lmodern` and then `fourier` and the result seems correct but I agree symbols `\nabla`  `\Delta` have heavier line width than `\box`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lmodern} %and then fourier

\begin{document}

$  \hat\Box \nabla  \Delta$  

\begin{align*}
\Box &= \sum_a \partial^a\partial_a \,, &
\hat\Box &= \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a
\end{align*}  
\end{document}
```

Finally I prefer :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,fourier} 
\begin{document}

$  \hat\square \nabla  \Delta$  

\begin{align*}
\square &= \sum_a \partial^a\partial_a \,, &
\hat\square &= \sum_a \mathcal{D}^a\mathcal{D}_a
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: with lmodern]
[image: with fourier and square]

Comment: Thanks Altermundus. I think that the best/easiest solution might be to use `\square`, that way the result is not too font dependent. I'll leave the question open for a little while to see if anyone else has suggestions.

Comment: @Simon You use what font for the mathematics ?

Comment: amsfonts? I'm writing a memoir class document and have the following packages loaded: `\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,nccmath,latexsym,mathtools}`
`\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}`