# Typeset d'Alembertian operator in 'classicthesis'

Tags: classicthesis, eulervm

What are the proper latex inputs for typesetting the bare d'Alembertian operator, and the d'Alembertian operator with either a tilde or a hat or a bar on top in a document prepared using classicthesis documentclass? I understand that the package eulervm is used in classicthesis.

Comment: And how exactly does that operator look like? Can you provide a link or an image showing the operator?

Comment: See here for more inspiration: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20513

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all lets have a look on the possibilities we are having. The MWE needs LuaLaTeX for the `\mdlgwhtsquare` command, but I will propose solutions for pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX later on.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb} % !!! Carefull, incompatibility found here, please see below
\usepackage{unicode-math} % !!! Carefull, incompatibility found here, please see below
\newcommand{\test}[1]{#1 \tilde{#1} \widehat{#1} \hat{#1} \bar{#1} \overbar{#1} \overline{#1}\nabla \Delta}
\begin{document}
Latin Modern Math:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\test{\Box}$ \verb+\Box+ % !!! Carefull, incompatibility found here, please see below
\item $\test{\square}$ \verb+\square+ % !!! Carefull, incompatibility found here, please see below
\item $\test{\mdlgwhtsquare}$ \verb+\mdlgwhtsquare+ 
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%
\setmathfont{Asana-math.otf}

Asana Math:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\test{\Box}$ \verb+\Box+ 
\item $\test{\square}$ \verb+\square+ 
\item $\test{\mdlgwhtsquare}$ \verb+\mdlgwhtsquare+ 
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%
\setmathfont{Xits-math.otf}

XITS Math
\begin{itemize}
\item $\test{\Box}$ \verb+\Box+ 
\item $\test{\square}$ \verb+\square+ 
\item $\test{\mdlgwhtsquare}$ \verb+\mdlgwhtsquare+ 
\end{itemize}    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

The last version, taken from `unicode-math` results in a good kerning for all solutions. So using LuaLaTeX you could do this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\dalembert}[1][]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{\mdlgwhtsquare}{#1\mdlgwhtsquare}}
\begin{document}
$\dalembert \dalembert[\tilde] \dalembert[\hat] \dalembert[\bar]$
\end{document}
```

which yields the following image for Latin Modern Math:

[image]

For pdfLaTeX it can just be achieved like this (I just found out, that the kerning issue above was not a problem with pdfLaTeX. [You can read here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175860) that `unicode-math` and `amssymb` are not compatible):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\dalembert}[1][]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{\Box}{#1\Box}}

\begin{document}
$\dalembert \dalembert[\tilde] \dalembert[\hat] \dalembert[\bar]$
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The most common notation seems to be a square. So I suggest to declare it as a math operator, to ensure proper spacing in formulae. I don't know if `eulervm` has a `Box` command. You can find it in `latexsym`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`,`mathabx`, `wasysymb`, &c.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dalembert}{\Box}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \dalembert (f)  & = \frac{1}{c² } \diffp[2]{f}{t} -  \diffp[2]{f}{x} -  \diffp[2]{f}{y}  -  \diffp[2]{f}{z} \\
\widehat\dalembert²(f) &  =  \dots
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you seem to have entered this answer twice.  you should delete one of them (after checking to see if one is correct and one isn't, of course).

Comment: @barbara beeton: Oh yes, thanks! I modified my answer, due to a typo, and thought it was only modified, not answered twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [D'Alembert Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) is *just* a box I don't think the `eulervm` package should modify it at all. Without a MWE I can not test it in context, but I'm pretty sure that these

```tex
$\Box = \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$
$\hat{\Box}$
$\tilde{\Box}$
```

work as expected.