# Why does unicode-math break the kerning of accents in combination with amssymb?

Tags: unicode-math

I am using the following MWE. First time with `unicode-math`, second time without it:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$\tilde\Box \hat\Box \bar\Box$   
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Where does the difference come from? The kerning is clearly broken.

> amssymb.sty 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
>
> unicode-math.sty 2013/05/21 v0.7e Unicode mathematics support for XeTeX and LuaTeX

### Edit

Barbara Beeton suggested to try the package `latexsym` instead of `amssymb`. This results in worse vertical positioning and the very same effect for I/O `unicode-math`:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$\tilde\Box \hat\Box \bar\Box$   
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `latexsym` also defines `\Box`.  what happens when you use that one instead of `amssymb`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've tried that and added the non-pleasant result to my OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `amssymb` together with `unicode-math`. The `\Box` command can be substituted with the (not really clearly named) `\mdlgwhtsquare` command (for `U+25A1 WHITE SQUARE`).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\renewcommand{\Box}{\mdlgwhtsquare}

\begin{document}
$\tilde{\Box} \hat{\Box} \bar{\Box}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping, not to get this answer, as it does not help me with my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175853 But as you say that both packages are incompatible, my main question is answered herewith.